# Locations of pixels that meet a specific criterion

Tags: matlab, location, pixel

In `matlab` the following means `return me the values of x for which y=1`

```
c = x(y == 1)
```

But, how can I return back the `location` of those pixels.

I tried:

```
 [i,j] = x(y == 1)
```

But, got the following error:

```
??? Indexing cannot yield multiple results.
```

How can I solve this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `find`

```
ind=find(y==val)
```

for example:

```
y=[1 0 2 0 3];
find(y==3)

ans =
     5
```

Or for matrices:

```
 y=[1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 7 8 9];
 [row col] = find(y==5)

row =
     2
col =
     2
```

Comment: When I used this I amazingly get the wrong results.

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong, look at my example

Comment: just to add that `[val ind]=find(y==3)` will yeild both positions and values...

Comment: @natan. Thanks for your reply. This is the function that I'm writing. Do you think there is something wrong in it why I get the wrong results using your method? http://pastie.org/private/gfg0tffkokl3gdenmag

Comment: @Count. Thanks for your reply. If you see the example at the link here. I couldn't understand what the output means. Can you kindly clarify it to me a bit? Thanks http://pastie.org/private/rafvkvchngf6r6iaea8jba

Comment: there are several bugs in your code. for example it isn't clear if `x` or `y` are vector or 2D matrices. When you try to assign a value to `x(i,j)` it means it is a 2D matrix, but from you code it seems it is a vector (from the for loop).  I recommend to go a different site to get your code debugged.

Comment: @natan. Those are the inputs for instance: http://pastie.org/private/md4orvspfhminxh7yxrm1g Aren't they fine?

Comment: since they are matrices you can use find in the following way: `[row col]=find(y==1)` see my edited answer

Comment: @natan. I changed my function to be as in the link here and changed it according to your new edit. If you see, the answer is correct except that I have `(1,1)` which isn't the case? Do you think `x` has been checked also for the existence of `1` in it although I need this only for `y`? Thanks http://pastie.org/private/kwhyh1uwfsr8pmrzlztca

Comment: In the code you look for the indices of elements of x equal to one (`[row column] = find(x==1)`), so if instead you want the indices of `y==1`, I'd change `x` to `y` in the `find` input.